# File served through script not updating from cache properly

Tags: php, http, caching

I created a script that serves private files from outside of the domains folder. The intent behind the script is to use some PHP script to verify that whoever is requesting the file has proper access to what they are asking for.

For the sake of trying to avoid asking repeatedly for a file the user has already downloaded, I added some headers to establish caching rules for the file. So far, everything appears to be working correctly for determining if the file served has since changed. However despite no longer sending a 304 Not modified status, it's still sending the old file.
ex.:

- Request newly added file; serve file with 200 Ok code
- Request previously loaded file; serve 304 Not Modified code
- Change image, request newly changed image; **serve new file** with 200 Ok code

The only part that isn't working is serving the new image, my browser refuses to update it unless I do `Ctrl+F5`. If I dump just the raw data of the file, I can visually see that it's updating properly but as soon as I add the Content-type header, it refuses to update.

Here's a sample of the code I'm using to handle the caching headers
(actual values are determined before the script reaches this part, and they aren't really relevant)

```
<?php
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$path = '/0001/user/';
$filesize = 300000;
$filetype = 'image/jpeg';
$created = '2023-10-17 12:00:00';
$modified = '2023-10-17 13:00:00';

$etag = md5($filename.$modified);

// Set expiration date to 30 days from the current date
$expiration = strtotime('+30 days');
$expiration = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $expiration);

// Set the "Cache-Control" header to specify private caching for 30 days
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000');
header('Expires: '.$expiration);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] === $etag) {
        // The client's cached version matches the current version, send a 304 Not Modified response
        $serverLastModified = max(strtotime($modified), strtotime($created));
        
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $serverLastModified));
        header('ETag: '.$etag);
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        die;
    }
} else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) {
    // If the browser has a cached version, check if it's up to date
    $clientLastModified = strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
    $serverLastModified = max(strtotime($modified), strtotime($created));
    
    if ($clientLastModified >= $serverLastModified) {
        // The client's cached version is up to date, send a 304 Not Modified response
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $serverLastModified));
        
        // Add an ETag header for cache validation
        header('ETag: '.$etag);
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        die;
    }
}

// Add an ETag header for cache validation
header('ETag: '.$etag);

// Set the "Last-Modified" header using the most recent date
$lastModifiedDate = max(strtotime($modified), strtotime($created));
$lastModifiedDateFormatted = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $lastModifiedDate);
header('Last-Modified: '.$lastModifiedDateFormatted);

// Output file to browser
header('Content-type: '.$filetype);

// Flush output buffer and send headers
clearstatcache();
if (ob_get_length()) {
    ob_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
}
flush();

readfile(__DIR__.'/../../private/'.$path.$filename);
```

In case it helps at all, here are the headers as sniffed by redbot.org

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000
Expires: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 13:09:12 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
ETag: "92951e93c30b48ff39298b48877a0ccb"
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Oct 2023 18:09:23 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 12:09:12 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46",
        h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443";
        ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,
        h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-27=":443";
        ma=2592000
```

Comment: `"The comparison with the stored ETag uses the weak comparison algorithm, meaning two files are considered identical if the content is equivalent — they don't have to be identical byte by byte. For example, two pages that differ by their creation date in the footer would still be considered identical."` - not sure if that is relevant

Comment: Is there any `Vary` header in the responses? (Not seeing you add one in your code, but perhaps something outside - web server - adds one.)

Comment: @CBroe it seems as though my server is forcing a Vary: User-agent header. Does that affect caching, and if so in what way?

Comment: The `Vary` header specifies which request headers, when changed, would make this constitute a different entity, from the caching point of view. But I doubt that your browser makes those two requests using _different_ User-Agent values.

Comment: I've edited to added all of the headers that are being sent by both the script and the server. Any idea if anything inside is causing the issue?

Comment: If there is a Cache-Control header with the max-age or s-maxage directive in the response, the Expires header is ignored. -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires)

Comment: Aside of that above -- Why do you use "Expires" resp. Cache-Control's "max-age"? See [MDN on Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control). I'm not posting an answer yet, as I'm not sure why you set your Caching Headers like that, but this sounds like the point to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** The class (mentioned below) has now become a [composer package](https://packagist.org/packages/volkerschulz/file-cache). Usage is as simple as:

```php
// Create instance 
$filecache = new FileCache('testfiles/cache.png');

// Respond to request
$filecache->respond();
```

It takes care of processing the request, creating and comparing hashes and responding with the correct headers. Feedback is appreciated.

**Original answer**:

**TL;DR;** The solution posted by @Olivier in their answer is probably suitable for most use cases.

However, there are a couple of things to consider.

1. **Any** request comes with an additional time penalty and will use resources on both, client and server. Setting `Cache-Control: no-cache` means, that every time the resource is used by the client, there will be a request to the web server. If the resource wasn't modified, the payload will not be transferred, but the overhead, a request comes with, will still be there. So if, at the time of a request, you can be sure the resource won't be changing for another *X* seconds, it would be better to use something like `Cache-Control: max-age=X; must-revalidate` (where *X* is the number of seconds the resource won't be stale for). If your resource changes on a regular basis, you could additionally use the header `Age: Y` (where *Y* is the age of the resource in seconds). For example: If you created the resource via cron job every 10 minutes, last time 2 minutes ago, your headers could look something like

   ```
   Cache-Control: max-age=600; must-revalidate
   Age: 120
   ```

   The client will automatically subtract the `Age` (120) from the `max-age` (600).
2. Resources might change **more often than once a second**. When using `Last-Modified` to identify a modification, this could lead to problems. Consider a change at second 0.1 (Version 1.0), a request at second 0.3, another change at second 0.8 (Version 2.0) and then no further changes for one hour. The client would then use (the stale) Version 1.0 for another hour, because Version 1.0 and Version 2.0 carry the same modification time. Might seem unlikely at first glance but is quite common for log files, for example. For that kind of files it would be better to use an `ETag` with either the file size or (if the file is not growing constantly) an `ETag` with a combination of file size and last modification time.
3. The last modification time **might change w/out the contents actually changing**, e.g. when `touch`ing a resource. In this case it would probably be best to use an `Etag` with (a hash of) the file size only or even with a complete file hash. While the latter will cost a lot of CPU and I/O time on the server, it is the safest approach and might be suitable for very large resources and/or slow connections.

I tried to cover all of these scenarios with a single PHP class, which can be found [here](https://github.com/volkerschulz/FileCache). While it is lacking proper documentation yet, it should be self-explanatory for the most part. Everybody feel free to comment and/or contribute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an ETag or expiration for what you want. The `Last-Modified` mechanism is enough. And, most importantly, you need to use the correct value for `Cache-Control`. which is `no-cache`. Despite its name, the no-cache directive doesn't mean that the resource can't be cached; it just means that the browser must validate it with the server before using it.

Here is a simple example of a script that serves a file named data.txt:

```
<?php
// Get the modification time of the resource
$dataTime = filemtime('data.txt');

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
{
    $sinceTime = strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
    if($sinceTime==$dataTime)
    {
        // The browser already has the latest version of the resource
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        exit;
    }
}

// Send the resource
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', $dataTime));
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
readfile('data.txt');
?>
```

Comment: I stripped out all of the other caching methods I tried and am limiting myself to using just Cache-Control and Last-Modified as per your suggestion, and things seem to be working very well. I'm a bit confused as to why documentation I found for establishing caches would mention multiple methods if it creates a conflict. Would you happen to know if there's any instances where the other methods would be deemed better?

Comment: @Chaosxmk Etags can be useful in situations where you have no date (or no reliable date, e.g. if the same file is overwritten, its date changes but the content does not). Imagine that you have a document associated with a version number, you could use the version number as an Etag.

Comment: @Chaosxmk If you use expiration, the browser will use the cached copy until it expires. It means that, if a new version is available on the server in the meantime, the browser won't see it.

Comment: @Olivier Quick suggestion: Using `$dataTime = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime('data.txt'))` in the beginning and omitting `strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])` for comparison should improve performance significantly.